# Dask DataFrame groupby/apply efficiency

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I am struggling to come up with an efficient way of solving what seems to be a typical use case of `dask.dataframe` `groupby`+`apply` and am wondering if I'm missing something obvious ([various](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory.html) [docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-performance.html) speak to this issue but I haven't been able to fully resolve it).

In short, I'm trying to load a medium-sized (say 10GB) dataframe, group by some column, train a machine learning model for each subset (a few seconds per model, ~100k subsets), and save that model to disk. My best attempt so far looks like:

```
c = Client()
df = dd.read_parquet('data.parquet')
df = c.persist(dd.set_index('key'))  # data is already sorted by key
result = c.compute(df.groupby(df.index).apply(train_and_save_model))
```

No matter how I try to `repartition` the data, I seem to spend an enormous amount of time on serialization/IO compared to on actual computation. A silly naive workaround of writing 100k separate Parquet files up front and then passing filenames to the workers to load/train on seems to be much more efficient; I'm struggling to see why that would perform any differently. Isn't the idea of setting the index and partitioning that each worker understands which parts of the file it should read from? I assume I'm missing something obvious here so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious, if you were to call `wait(df)` after the `dd.set_index` line which part would take up the most time?  I'd also be curious to know the performance of `dd.read_parquet(...).groupby('key').apply(...)` without the distributed scheduler, but just using the default threaded scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a big difference between data that is read in with `index='key'` and data that is re-indexed with `set_index`; I thought that if the new index was already sorted then there'd be no shuffling cost but I guess that was wrong.

Changing to `dd.read_parquet('data.parquet', index='key')` seems to give performance like what I was hoping for so I'm happy (though still curious why `set_index` seems to shuffle unnecessarily in this case).

Comment: `set_index` should check for sortedness of the column in a single initial pass through the data.  I would be mildly surprised to learn that 1. you're on a version of dask less than a year old, 2. the data was sorted, 3. you experienced a shuffle.

Comment: Not sure if this will qualify as a mild surprise but I've posted a reproducible example here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3135